# Request.cookies not returning all the cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, configuration, httpwebrequest

I do know that Request.Cookies will return cookies.
But I do have a cookie which I have created during my application and I want to retrieve it later.
But Request.Cookies["cookie name"] is not returning. I can see in CookieManager in FF that cookie still exists.
Any idea why?

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the expiration hasn't passed.
- Check that the domain it was issued under is the same as the one it is being read from.
- Check that the cookie wasn't issued using SSL and is attempting to be read via an non-encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem in vb.net, based on @Heather answer. I realised that a cookie I was reading, requires a SSL connection. It is possible to check if this works when the `isSecure` flag is set to false under Cookie Manager.

My solution passed through configure Visual Studio to work with IIS Express and set up to work with SSL/HTTPS. [This link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) helped me.